# Using method of Undetermined coefficients to solve $y'''' + y'' = 3x^2 + 4\sin x - 2\cos x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the differential eqn I am having trouble with

$$y'''' + y'' = 3x^2 + 4\sin x - 2\cos x$$

So I am supposed to solve this by method of undetermined coefficients.

So the characteristic equation should be $m^4 + m^2 = 0$

so $m=0$ (repeated) and  $m=\pm i$ (euler identity)

$y_h = c_1 + (A\cos x + B\sin x)$

Now to find the complete solution I need to find yp.

So according to the Sum rule $y =y_h + y_{p1} + y_{p2}$

to get $y_{p1}$,

So I am now supposed to first solve $y'''' + y'' = 3x^2$

So let a sol be

$$y_{p1} = K_2x^2 + K_1x + K_0$$
So, 
\begin{align*}
y_{p1}'&= 2K_2x + K_1\\
y_{p1}''&= 2K_2\\
y_{p1}''''&= 0
\end{align*}
This is the part where I get stuck
Substituting values of y to find the coefficients we get
$$2K_2 = 3x^2$$

$$K_2 = 0?$$
There must be something wrong here.

NOTE: I am following the process of solving higher order ODEs as mentioned in the book Advanced Engineering Mathematics by Erwin Kreyszig 9th edition.

Sorry for the bad formatting, this is the first time I am posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First since $m=0$ is of multiplicity two the homogeneous solution is
$$y_h=c_1+c_2x+c_3 \cos x+c_4 \sin x$$
Now for the particular solution
$$y'''' + y'' = 3x^2$$
Susbtitute $y''=z$ then the equation becomes
$$z'' + z= 3x^2$$
Use $z_p=Ax^2+Bx+C$ as a particular solution
Then you find 
$$z_p=3x^2-6$$
Integrate twice to find $y_p$
$$y_p''=3x^2-6$$

Edit
second part I used
$$z_p=x(A\cos x + B \sin x)$$
For this equation
$$z''+z=4 \sin x -2 \cos x$$
Then I got
$$(A,B)=(-2,-1)$$
Integrate by part but take first part of the integration since the second part is absorbed by the homogeneous solution
$$y''_p=-x \sin x -2x \cos x$$
First integration
$$y'_p=x \cos x -2 x\sin x$$
Second integration. Finally:
$$\boxed {y_p=x \sin x +2 x\cos x}$$

Comment: Thank You! I will try it by substitution too.

Comment: yw @SohamBhattacharya yes it's easier to substitute first then find the particular solution and finally integrate

Comment: Can you help me out with yp2?

Comment: I added some lines I hope it's clear @SohamBhattacharya

Answer (score 3):

Since $m=0$ is a root of the characteristic equation and their multiplicity is $2$, and $\pm i$ are two complex conjugated roots it follows
$$y_h=c_1+c_2x+c_3\cos x+c_4\sin x$$
At a first glance we can think about $y_{p1}=Ax^2+Bx+C$ and $y_{p2}=E\cos x+F\sin x$, but these two particular solutions contains solutions of the associated homogeneous DE, so we must to modify them properly:
$$y_{p1}=\color{red}{x^2}\left(Ax^2+Bx+C\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad y_{p2}=\color{red}{x}\left(E\cos x+F\sin x\right)$$

Comment: Thank You So much. How did I not notice that.